# Permanently set environment variables using Ansible

Tags: linux, ansible

I am trying to set up a cluster, I need to set permanent environment variables on the created Vms (Ubuntu/xenial).

I am using vagrant and ansible, but I didn’t find out the appropriate automated way to do it.

**Troubleshooting:**

1. I tried to do it manually using :

```
export VAR = “value”
```

It works but it’s not permanent.

2. I tried also to edit the ~/.bashrc file to add the command above, I don’t think that’s right.

I am asking if someone could help me.

Thank you.

Comment: You need permanent BASH variables? that are available for NON-ansible availability? Or you need variables that are permanent only for Ansible?

Comment: I need them for non-ansible availability.
I tried a blockinfile with ansible to add the export command
at the end of the .bashrc file. But I don't think it's the best way.

Comment: Something like "permanent environment variable" doesn't exists. A process can always change it's environment or run `execvpe` where it controls child process environment. You can add `readonly VAR` to bashrc. Adding `export VAR` to bashrc will make the variable visible to processes that are child from the bash process (that sources bashrc).

Comment: if you append `export VAR="value"` to `.bashrc` and then re-login to the server, do you not get the value if you do `env` or `echo $VAR` ?

Comment: No after a re-login I didn't get the $VAR, I am asking if ```.bashrc``` is the right file to edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you.

I wrote this ansible-playbook and it's working.

```
- hosts: localhost
  become_user: root
  tasks:

    - name: Adding KUBECONFIG variable
      delegate_to: localhost
      copy:
        content: export KUBECONFIG="/etc/config/admin.conf/admin.conf"
        dest: /etc/profile.d/kubeconfig.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Ansible only to set these needed VARs

You can append to `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc`

```
export VAR="value"
```

which will be available when user logins using shell=/bin/bash, it will not load if shell=/bin/sh or other..

Comment: Appending to `/etc/profile` or a new file in `/etc/profile.d` is the generic way of doing that; just watch out that `export VAR="value"` is bash specific; the POSIX way needs them to be two separate statements `VAR="value"; export VAR`

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try this.